# Generic method to get an instance from a class parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class with subclasses:

```
class Item<T>
{
     //
}

class IntItem extends Item<Integer>
{
    //
}
```

I need a method to get an instance of Item from its class. I tried methods like:

```
<T extends Item<T>> T getItem(Class<T> itemClass)
{
  return ...
}


<T> Item<T> getItem(Class<Item<T>> itemClass)
{
    return ...
}
```

But it does not work:

```
// Does not compile: "inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints Integer,IntItem"
IntItem ii = getItem(IntItem.class);
```

What is the correct way to do this ?

**EDIT after cardinal system answer**

Note that question is only related to the generics/method signatures.

Same question but passing an item instance as parameter:

```
IntItem ii = getItem2(anIntItem); 

static <T extends Item<E>,E> T getItem(Class<T> itemClass)
{
    return ...
}

static <T extends Item<E>,E> T getItem2(T item)
{ 
     // Does not compile: "error: incompatible types: Item cannot be converted to T"
     return getItem(item.getClass();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your `getItem` method needs a separate generic parameter to set on your `Item` parameter (I'm going to use `E`). Secondly, just use [`Class#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

```
public static <T extends Item<E>, E> T getItem(Class<T> itemType)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return itemType.newInstance();
}
```

You can also omit the `extends Item<?>` part entirely. While this will allow the method to instantiate instances of other types, it will still work perfectly for Item types.

If in the future you wanted to add parameters to your item constructors, you could use [`Class#getConstructor(Class<?>...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) or [`Class#getConstructors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--) to find the constructor you want to use, then
[`Constructor#newInstance(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) to create your instance. Here are two examples:

```
// This example does NOT work with null arguments
public static <T> T getItem(Class<T> itemType, Object... arguments)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = Arrays.stream(arguments).map(Object::getClass).toArray(Class[]::new);
    return getItem(itemType, parameterTypes, arguments);
}

// This example works with null arguments
public static <T> T getItem(Class<T> itemType, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] arguments)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Constructor<T> constructor = itemType.getConstructor(parameterTypes);
    return constructor.newInstance(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Your "firstly" solves my problem, you'll get the answer. But I realize there is a side issue, I'll update my question.